# hover effect data-letters text-align

Tags: css, hover, text-align

Hello i try to make a hover effect on my menu list with data-letters, so it' s work really good but i want to make it in text-align: right, the problem is that when i add it to my menu-item, i can' t see the data-letters :/
anyone have a solution ? 
there is my code:

```css
.link {
 outline: none;
 text-decoration: none;
 position: relative;
 color: #9e9ba4;
 display:inline-block;
}


.link--over {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 overflow: hidden;
 color: #c5c2b8;
 
}

.link--over:hover {
 color: #c5c2b8;
}

.link--over::after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 height: 3px;
 width: 100%;
 top: 20%;
 margin-top: -1.5px;
 right: 0;
 background: rgba(51,51,51,1);
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%,0,0);
 transform: translate3d(-100%,0,0);
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s;
 transition: transform 0.4s;
 -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
 transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
}

.link--over:hover::after {
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
 transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
}

.link--over::before {
 content: attr(data-letters);
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 150;
 overflow: hidden;
 display:block;
 color: #424242;
 white-space: nowrap;
 letter-spacing:10px;
 width: 0%;
 -webkit-transition: width 0.4s 0.3s;
 transition: width 0.4s 0.3s;
}

.link--over:hover::before {
 width: 100%;
}

.menu-item{
 position:absolute;
 left:50%;
 margin-left:-50px;
 margin-top:20%;
 width:150px;
  text-align:right;
 
}

.menu-item li {
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
 letter-spacing:10px;
 margin-bottom:40px;
}

#en-cours{
 color:rgba(51,51,51,1);
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu-item">
           
             <a id="en-cours" class="link link--over" href="index.html" data-letters="works"><li>works</li></a>
            <a class="link link--over" href="#" data-letters="about"><li>about</li></a>
            <a class="link link--over" href="#" data-letters="contact"><li>contact</li></a>
       
            </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you be against throwing some 
 tags between each item? I also added text-align:right to many CSS items:

```css
.link {
 outline: none;
 text-decoration: none;
 position: relative;
 color: #9e9ba4;
 display:inline-block;
}


.link--over {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 overflow: hidden;
 color: #c5c2b8;
    text-align: right; 
}

.link--over:hover {
 color: #c5c2b8;
}

.link--over::after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 height: 3px;
 width: 100%;
 top: 20%;
 margin-top: -1.5px;
 right: 0;
 background: rgba(51,51,51,1);
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%,0,0);
 transform: translate3d(-100%,0,0);
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s;
 transition: transform 0.4s;
 -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
 transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
    text-align: right;
}

.link--over:hover::after {
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
 transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
}

.link--over::before {
 content: attr(data-letters);
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 150;
 overflow: hidden;
 color: #424242;
 white-space: nowrap;
 letter-spacing:10px;
 width: 0%;
 -webkit-transition: width 0.4s 0.3s;
 transition: width 0.4s 0.3s;
    text-align: right;
}

.link--over:hover::before {
 width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
}

.menu-item{
 position:absolute;
 left:50%;
 margin-left:-50px;
 margin-top:20%;
 width:150px;
 
}

.menu-item li {
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
 letter-spacing:10px;
 margin-bottom:40px;
    text-align: right;
}

#en-cours{
 color:rgba(51,51,51,1);
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu-item">
           
             <a id="en-cours" class="link link--over menu-item" href="index.html" data-letters="works"><li>works</li></a>
    <br>
            <a class="link link--over menu-item" href="#" data-letters="about"><li>about</li></a>
    <br>
            <a class="link link--over menu-item" href="#" data-letters="contact"><li>contact</li></a>
       
            </ul>
```

Comment: no as you can see on your code it' s exactly the problem i have, when you put a text-align right you can not get the data-letters visible

Comment: i edit my code now i can get it but i have a little problem of margin i dont know where it s come from :/

Comment: do you have a jsfiddle link for it?

Comment: I added a bit to the margin-left:-50px to make it -125px, its not ideal though. you might have to find a way to center the div the options  are held within... http://jsfiddle.net/omikey/hqft3218/1/ - by the way, its really a cool effect you made there

Comment: no the problem is about the data-letter, the hover effect, you can see that when you hover a link an other text come upstair, it s that have a margin that i want to change